# UIWebView: Save cookie state across app restarts

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, uiwebview

I developing an application with Swift and an UIWebView that opens a webapp.
Each time our users open the app, they need to login again because the app is not storing cookies. How can i solve it?

I tried this to store cookies:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    println(request.URL!.absoluteString)


    var cookiesData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies!)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(cookiesData, forKey: "savedCookies")

    return true
}
```

And to retrieve cookies again:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicy.Always
let cookies = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("cookies"))
```

I don't know how can i retrieve cookies in an array and iterate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

To save cookie

```
    let cookieJar: NSHTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(cookieJar.cookies)
    let ud: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ud.setObject(data, forKey: "cookie")
```

To retrieve cookie

```
    let ud: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let data: NSData? = ud.objectForKey("cookie") as? NSData
    if let cookie = data {
        let datas: NSArray? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(cookie) as? NSArray
        if let cookies = datas {
            for c in cookies as! [NSHTTPCookie] {
                NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(c)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great! Where I put this code? where and when I call the function to retrieve cookies? and save them?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer in Objective-C:

To save cookies:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cookieJar.cookies];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"Cookies"];
```

To load cookies:

```
NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"Cookies"];
if (data) {
    NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    if (cookies) {
        for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
            [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4** (and without force unwrap)

```
func saveCookie() {
    let cookieJar: HTTPCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    if let cookies = cookieJar.cookies {
        let data: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: cookies)
        let ud: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        ud.set(data, forKey: "cookie")
    }
}

func loadCookie() {
    let ud: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let data: Data? = ud.object(forKey: "cookie") as? Data
    if let cookie = data {
        let datas: NSArray? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: cookie) as? NSArray
        if let cookies = datas {
            for c in cookies {
                if let cookieObject = c as? HTTPCookie {
                    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookieObject)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call `saveCookie()` in the `didFinishNavigation` method for example (or in `webViewDidFinishLoad` if you are using `UIWebView` and not `WKWebView`).

And you can call `loadCookie()` in the `viewDidLoad` or before you initialize the `webView`.